# Linearization of problem with affine linear functions

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

Problem: Write the following task as a linear program: $\min f(x),x\in[-2,5]$ where

\begin{align}f(x) := \begin{cases}
  -2x+2,&\quad-2\le x<-1\\    
  -x+3,&\quad-1\le x < 1\\
2,&\quad1\le x<3\\
0.5x+0.5,&\quad3\le x<4\\
3x-9.5,&\quad4\le x\le5.
\end{cases}\end{align}
TIP: f(x) can be written as the maximum of 5 affine linear functions

While the solution is rather obvious ($2$), I don't quite know how I would write this as a linear program with this tip. Some thoughts of mine:

\begin{align}\min&\quad y\\\text{s.t.}&\quad
y \ge -2x_1 +2\\&\quad
y \ge -x_2+3\\&\quad
y \ge 2\\&\quad
y \ge 0.5x_3+0.5\\&\quad
y \ge -3x_4+9.5\end{align}
for $x_1 \in [-2,1)$, $x_2 \in [-1,1)$ etc.
But this obviously leads to a wrong solution of the problem. The rest of the exercises were super easy and this is an introductory operations research course for economists, so it shouldn't be too hard. I just cant come up with a good solution to this and the tip is confusing me more than it is helping me. Is there a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right idea, but just use $x$ in place of each $x_i$.  That is, you need only two variables, $x$ and $y$, with $-2\le x\le 5$, and the problem is to minimize $y$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
y &\ge -2x+2 \\    
y &\ge -x+3 \\
y &\ge 2 \\
y &\ge 0.5x+0.5 \\
y &\ge 3x-9.5 \\
\end{align}
The corresponding feasible region looks like the topmost portion of this plot, where I have labeled the breakpoints:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gkf5nfpvxi

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wouldn't that lead to wrong results? For any $x$ between $-2$ and $5$ it seems to be that there is one constraint larger than $2$.

Comment: It works for $x=1$, I just see. But isn't that somewhat random? Like we couldn't write the program this way if we didn't know that $2$ is the optimal solution already. For example if we add to $f: f(x) := 6 , 5<x\le6$ than it already wouldn't work that way anymore.

Comment: I see now that you had flipped some signs in the last part, so maybe that caused some confusion about whether this will work.  I explicitly added the correct constraints to my answer.  The ability to do this LP formulation relies on the fact that the slopes are increasing.  For minimization of a nonconvex piecewise-linear function, you would need to introduce binary variables and other constraints.